# string::find() is unable to find substring a from large string b

Tags: c++, string

I want to search substring a from string b which is storing a continuously by input and I want to know if a is repeatedly input

So, I am adding substring a to b, one by one and after input and find a in b so that if it is already present it can give output as found

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,t=0;
    cin>>n;
    string b;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        string a;
        cin>>a;
        if (b.find(a) != std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << "found!" << '\n';
        }
        for(int j=0; j<a.length();j++){
            b[j+t]= a[j];
        }
        t += (a.length());
        a.clear();
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings can resize when needed, but not via `operator[]`. You are invoking undefined behavior here:

```
    for(int j=0; j<a.length();j++){
        
        
        b[j+t]= a[j];
    }
```

`b` starts out as an empty string and you never increase its size, hence `b[j+t]` is an out-of-bounds access for any `j+t != 0` (`std::string::operator[]` has the fine sublety that you are allowed to access `my_string[ my_string.size()]`. It returns a reference to the terminating null character, but modifying that invokes undefined behavior as well).

To add one string to another use `operator+=` which correctly adjusts the size of `b`:

```
 b += a;
```

However, the better solution would be to store strings in a `std::vector<std::string>` and search for duplicates in that vector, or use a `std::set<std::string>`. Because with your current approach `"foobar"` is recognized as duplicate of previously entered `"foo"` and `"bar"`.

Comment: If the goal is the find exact matches, `std::set<std::string>` or `std::unordered_set<std::string>` may be more useful.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes I mentioned `std::set`, but one thing at a time. Before adding more confusion OP should to get their strings right (even if in the next step the concatenation isnt needed, well... on a second thought, there is a more direct way to the right solution, but I still like the answer as it is ;)